Why won't DataGrip let me query a table?
I can create or delete a table in VSCode like so:
def write_to_RS(query):
    try:
        secret_arn = session.client('secretsmanager').get_secret_value(SecretId=rs_secret_id)['ARN']

        # Initializing Redshift client
        logger.info("Initializing Redshift's client ...")
        config = Config(connect_timeout=180, read_timeout=180)
        client_redshift = session.client("redshift-data", config=config)

        client_redshift.execute_statement(Database=db,
                                          SecretArn=secret_arn,
                                          Sql=query,
                                          ClusterIdentifier=cluster_id)
        
        permissions_update = "GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA my_schema TO GROUP admin"
        
        client_redshift.execute_statement(Database=db,
                                    SecretArn=secret_arn,
                                    Sql=permissions_update,
                                    ClusterIdentifier=cluster_id)
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(e)

q = """
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS address (
    account_id INT,
    street VARCHAR,
    city VARCHAR,
    country VARCHAR
)
"""

write_to_RS(q)

# write_to_RS('DROP TABLE address')

but when i try to open it or query it in DataGrip directly (like select count(*) from address), it throws an error:
[42501] ERROR: permission denied for relation address
I am using the same credential connecting to DataGrip as I'm using in the VSCode script to create/delete the table.
Why it be like that :|
Does public schema have unchangeable default permissions or something?

What do you mean by "when i try to open it or query it in DataGrip directly"? Are you running the same code in DataGrip (presumably not) or are you connecting to the Redshift database from DataGrip and running a command like select * from address? What credentials is DataGrip using when connecting to Redshift and what makes you think those credentials should be allowed to access the address table? Please add more details to your Question.

@JohnRotenstein yes, exactly. When i try to either doubleclick on the table to open it in a new tab, or query select * from address it throws the error. The credentials are the same between DataGrip and VSCode. I updated to question to include this information

I see that you are granting access IN SCHEMA my_schema. Perhaps the table is being created in a different schema, since no schema is specified for the table-creation schema? Try to connect to Redshift with a good SQL Client (like DataGrip) and see if you can find where the table was created and what permissions have been granted on it.
